# How can i connect my domain name to my heroku app

Tags: heroku, deployment

I buyed domain. After that i hosted app on heroku and now i am facing issues to linke my domain name with my app on heroku.I followed a lot of videos on internet but none of them is working.

Last one that i tried is:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=kKGSGT7mSnQ
```

but there when i try to copy paste my heroku app url in the points to field i get

```
Enter either @ or a valid host name such as: "subdomain.domain.tld"
```

error.

Can somoene tell my how can i do this thing please ?

Answer (score 0):

I need to add domain on heroku - example.com that generated dns target and that generated dns target needs to be pasted in the points to section in go daddy: It is not the full app url from heroku like previous...